# Method editString takes a string and breaks it into an array of single words which are then are edited based on the command

Tags: string, arraylist, replace, addition

This program uses three strings to modify the contents of the first. The first string makes up the sentence that needs to be modified, the second gives an order on what to do to the first string (remove, replace, or add), and finally, the third string, an array list, displays what should be changed about the first string.

These are three examples that I have been provided to ensure my program works:

```
editString("What is up bro", "remove", ["bro"]) returns ["What", "is", "up"]
editString("What is up bro", "replace", ["bro", "brother"]) returns ["What", "is", "up", "brother"]
editString("What is up", "add", ["my", "3", "friend", "4"]) returns ["What", "is", "up", "my", "friend"]
```

This is the code I have come up with so far. Though it is not much, I feel I at least have a good start on where to go with this program.

```
public static ArrayList<String> editString(String text, String command, ArrayList<String> words)
    {
        ArrayList<String> edited = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (command.equals('remove')) {
            text.set(words);
        }
        if (command.equals('replace')) {
            text.set(words);
        }
        if (command.equals('add')) {
            words[i] = replace;
        }
      return edited;
    }
```

If anybody has any suggestions on how to get this code to work, I would love to hear it. I am almost completely stuck on how to work this program, but I feel with a bit of guidance, I can get in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<String> editString(String text, String command, ArrayList<String> words)
    {
        String[] array = text.split("\\s+");
        ArrayList<String> edited = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (command.equals("remove")) {
            for(String word : array) {
                if(!words.contains(word)) {
                    edited.add(word);
                }
            }
        }

        if (command.equals("replace")) {
            for(String word : array) {
                if(words.contains(word)) {
                    int index = words.indexOf(word);
                    edited.add(words.get(index + 1));
                } else {
                    edited.add(word);
                }
            }
        }

        if (command.equals("add")) {
            for(String word : array) {
                edited.add(word);
            }
            int i = 1;
            while(i < words.size()) {
                edited.add(Integer.parseInt(words.get(i)), words.get(i - 1));
                i += 2;
            }
        }
        return edited;
    }
```

First, the input string should be split into words. And you have to perform an operation based on the command.
I have made few assumptions here as it was not mentioned:

1. The input for add operation has the word followed by its index in the output.
2. only one word is replaced in the replace operation and the word to be replaced lies at index 0.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion helped solve the examples I mentioned, but another test case I was given did not fully process. Here is the problematic code:
```
//editString("Tis but a flesh wound", "replace", ["flesh", "scratch", "wound", "mark"]) returns ["Tis", "but", "a", "scratch", "mark"]
```
Though it should be returning "Tis but a scratch mark", it is instead giving out "Tis but a scratch wound". Do you have any suggestions on how to get this line working? I believe the issue is that the code you have given me only takes in the first instance before moving on to another.

Comment: I have updated the replace condition. Hope it helps